# CI - GitHub - How to do some form of continuous integration without webhooks

Tags: git, bash, continuous-integration

So I am developing an app that will be installed on-site. We have a server that runs an update bash script every 15 minutes for code changes and every 2 hours for stored procedure changes. We store our code (and our stored procedures) in git and use Github as our central point.

We would like to be able to update our stored procedures / code when changes have been pushed to dev instead of on timed jobs. I realize github has webhooks but they require github to be able to hit an API on our end and due to our IT team this isn't possible.

Is there a way for us to be able to update our git repo's on our dev server in a more efficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just started checking this out on IFTTT and I didn't see a trigger for receiving a new push, but maybe there are some others that you can piggy back off of. There is a trigger for "any new issue" so maybe you use that and create an issue when you push that is your IFTTT trigger and then for the "that" action, send yourself an email and monitor your emails for this message. I know, hack-y, but at least one approach. Hopefully there is a better way to go here.

Another possible work around is to get a virtual server somewhere on the net that can receive the github webhook and that you can also connect via a socket and it will relay to you when it receives each github notification.